# net view displays only my own computer

Tags: networking, windows-xp

On Windows 7, I run `net view`. But only my own machine is displayed whereas I am supposed to see 8 others computers. However, the ping to those computers adrresses works fine.
Why net view does not display those machines ?

Comment: Is network discovery turned on?

Comment: Yes, it is activated (on)

Comment: What OS do the other computers run?

Comment: It is the same OS on all other computers (Windows 7) like me. I can ping them, but they are not shown on net view command.

Comment: Do they all have network discovery turned on?

Comment: I must check all the computers and see. Thank you.